# Mouse movement in a webpage using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner in Selenium webdriver. I'm trying to automate an action in [this](http://www.amazon.in/) website

In the webpage, I want to move the cursor to **"Shop by category"->"Mobiles&tablets"->then click the link "Android Mobiles".** But could not see the link Android phone clicked.

Could you guide me here, thanks.

Below is the code,

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    WebElement oEle1,oEle2;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\1003061\\Documents\\Automation testing\\selenium softwares\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.amazon.in/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Actions oMouse=new Actions(driver);
    oEle1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Category')]"));
    oMouse.moveToElement(oEle1).build().perform();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    oEle2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@aria-label='Mobiles & Tablets']/span[contains(text(),'Mobiles & Tablets')]"));
    oMouse.moveToElement(oEle2).build().perform();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'android_mobiles')]")).click();

}
```

Comment: You are misunderstanding how `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` works. implicitlyWait means that once you've set that property, selenium will wait 10 seconds before every single command it executes. You need only set this property once in your test, not after every single step. It is however recommended to not use this at all. You should use WebDriverWait instead.

Comment: Other than Mobrockers comment above to remove the implicitWaits, I don't see anything wrong with your code. I ran it on my machine using FF and it works fine. Have you tried running it with other browsers? Does it work?

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would not bother following the dropdown structure of this site. I would just execute a `javascript` command to click on the option you want.

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'android_mobiles')]"))
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Don't do this. A user can't click on a link that isn't visible. Selenium was designed to only interact with visible elements on the page because that's what the user has access to. If you do things like this, using JSE to access hidden elements, then you are not automating a user scenario.

Comment: Considering he is performming actions on the amazon webshop I doubt he is testing a user scenario and doesn't care about copying one precisely. He just wants to get to the page and this is the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the menu layout has changed in the last few months

I write a python script to navigate the cursor to the **"All mobile"** subitem menu

```
action =  ActionChains(driver);
```

First, I use the element id to move the cursor to **"Shop by category"**

```
category = driver.find_element_by_id('nav-link-shopall')

action.move_to_element(category);
action.perform();

sleep(0.1)
```

Then, using find_element_by_xpath i can locate the span element with the label **"Mobiles, Computers"**

< span class="nav-hasPanel                              nav-item" data-nav-panelkey="PhonesAccessoriesPanel" role="navigation" aria-label="Mobiles, Computers">                          < span class="nav-text">Mobiles, Computers< /span>                          < /span>

```
mobile = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[span='Mobiles, Computers']")


action.move_to_element(mobile);
action.perform();

sleep(0.1)
```

And finally

< span class="nav-text">All Mobile Phones< /span >

```
allmobile = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[span='All Mobile Phones']")


action.move_to_element(allmobile);
action.perform();

sleep(0.1)
allmobile.click();
```